# Changing a QuerySet object on the fly in Django

Tags: django, django-views

Can or should I ever do this in a view?

```
a = SomeTable.objects.all()
for r in a:
    if r.some_column == 'foo':
        r.some_column = 'bar'
```

It worked like a champ, but I tried a similar thing somewhere else and I was getting strange results, implying that QuerySet objects don't like to be trifled with.  And, I didn't see anything in the docs good or bad for this sort of trick.

I know there are other ways to do this, but I'm specifically wanting to know if this is a bad idea, why it's bad, and if it is indeed bad, what the 'best' most django/pythonic way to change values on the fly would be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is fine as long as you don't do anything later that will cause the queryset to be re-evaluated - for example, slicing it. That will make another query to the database, and all your modified objects will be replaced with fresh ones.

A way to protect yourself against that would be to convert to a list first:

```
a = list(SomeTable.objects.all())
```

This way, further slicing etc won't cause a fresh db call, and any modifications will be preserved.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel.  Your example is exactly what I meant when I said "I know there are other ways to do this", and I appreciate your clarification, too.  Oh, and your example of taking a slice is exactly what was causing the strange results I mentioned.  I'm a little embarrassed I didn't catch that, and I'm glad you pointed it out.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Yup.  See docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update)

```
SomeTable.objects.filter(some_column='foo').update(some_column='bar')
```

I would go with Django's idiom.  It executes the SQL with a single statement with 'where' and 'update' rather sending multiple SQL statements like your code would.  This saves time.  Check with Django's ['connection'](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running) to test SQL time.

Comment: Thanks, and I apologize if I wasn't clear, but I'm not interested in updating the database, just modifying the output for display purposes.